# How can I set the Name attribute of an input field using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, forms, attributes

Quick question... I was wondering how I can get this to happen.

Okay I have an input field like such:

```
<input type="text" id="input1" size="10" name="" value="" class="checked other_amount" onfocus="Toggle('radio1', 'input1');" />
```

I would like to click on a div with an ID of #resetPrompt and fill the empty name attr from the input with "other_amount"

I'm out of ideas its been a long day

Thanks guys,

Matt

Answer (score 77, accepted):

```
$('#resetPrompt').click(function(){
    $('#input1').attr('name', 'other_amount');
});
```

Comment: As pointed earlier, this won't work in MSIE7 and older. Workaround is to rewrite inner line using .prop(..):

$('#input1').attr('name', 'other_amount') || $('#input1').prop('name', 'other_amount');

Answer (score 5):

This is for all the googlers out there:

It should be noted that Alex's proposal, though functional in most "real" browsers, does not work in ie 8 and below (jquery 1.6.2). When setting the "name" attribute of an input field, Microsoft, to address a bug, added a fictitious "submitName" attribute when dynamic input fields are attached to the DOM.

To workaround the problem in ie, either force your users to upgrade, use Firefox, Chrome, etc. or you'll need to add the input field manually:

```
$("#resetPrompt").click(function(){
   $("#input1").remove();
   $("#input_container").append('<input id="input1" name="' + other_amount + "' type="text" class="checked other_amount" onFocus="Toggle(\'radio1\', \'input1\');" />');
});
```

Comment: Confirm: cannot set @name attribute with $.name(.., ..) in MSIE7 -- input simply retains old value and nothing happens. Is it addressed in more recent jQuery ver?

Answer (score 1):

If "other_amount" is the ID of the other input, use [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) and [val](http://api.jquery.com/val/) as follows:

```
$("#resetPrompt").click(function(){
    var otherValue = $("#other_amount").val();
    $("#input1").attr("name", "someName");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that "other_amount" is the name, not id of the corresponding input.

```
$('#resetPrompt').click( function() {
   $('#input1').attr('name', $('[name=other_amount]').val());
});
```