# How to combine 2 button to 1 button in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, button, hide

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#sakla").click(function(){
    $(".askforum").hide();


});
$("#getir").click(function(){
    $(".askforum").show();

});
```

Hi ! how can I combine two button function to one button ? I want to run two functions with one button. the button name should change when I clicked if its show it must be become hide. thanks

Comment: Please show your HTML. It's not clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) to toggle between shown and hidden. Change the two buttons into one button, and bind the click event to that button alone.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      var button = $('#thatnewbutton');
      
      button.click(function(){
        var forum = $(".askforum");
        forum.toggle();
        button.text(forum.is(':visible')?'Hide':'Show');
      });
      
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="thatnewbutton">Hide</button>
<div class='askforum'>Content</div>
```

Comment: thanks it worked but how can i change button name when clicked. for example if its hide, when clicked it should turn show.

Comment: Yeah, I updated the snippet.

Comment: thanks mate! i solved my problem.

Comment: [ahem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple demo:

```js
$(function() {
    $('.toggle').on('click', function() {
        var txt = $(this).text().trim();
        $(this).text( txt == 'HIDE' ? 'SHOW' : 'HIDE' );
        $('.whattotoggle').toggle();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="toggle">HIDE</button>
<div class="whattotoggle">Toggle This</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#thatnewbutton").click(function(){
    $(".askforum").toggle();
  });
});
```

Alternatively for changing the name, find attr name of the button and accordingly change it using attr function. 
    [How can I set the Name attribute of an input field using Jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338144/how-can-i-set-the-name-attribute-of-an-input-field-using-jquery)

Cheers!